# time error in controlling a clock

Tags: motor, attiny, oscillator-clock

I have [designed and 3d printed a clock](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:570797).

I am controlling the clock using a Arduino sketch running on a Attiny2313. The stepper motor I am using is a 12v 1:12 ratio stepper. The total number of steps per revolution are 288.

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to get the time right. I have got the steps per revolution of the minute ring bang on, but some how the motor gains 10/11 minutes every 24 hours.

I have used a lot of the code from the stepper motor library. I am not using the stepper motor library as the code gets larger than what can fit into the 2k attiny memory.

Any help is appreciated.

```
int number_of_steps = 288;
int motor_pin_1 = 9;
int motor_pin_2 = 10;
int motor_pin_3 = 11;
int motor_pin_4 = 12;
int ledpin = 13;
int delayTime = 4;
int buttonPin = 4;
int buttonState = 0; 
int enablepin = 8;
int whatspeed = 40;
int last_step_time =0;
int step_number = 0;
[color=red]int blinkDelay = 939; [/color]
int step_delay = 60L * 1000L / number_of_steps / whatspeed;
int step_direction = 0;
void setup() {


 pinMode(motor_pin_1, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(motor_pin_2, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(motor_pin_3, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(motor_pin_4, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(buttonPin,INPUT);
 pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(enablepin,OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
 buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
 if (buttonState ==HIGH){
   enablemotor();
   movestep(20);
   digitalWrite(ledpin,HIGH);
 }
 else{
   digitalWrite(ledpin,LOW);

   for (int xx = 0; xx<59;xx ++){

     enablemotor();
     movestep(42);
     //delay(100);
     motoroff();
     blinkk();
   }
   enablemotor();
   movestep(89);//85;

   motoroff();
   blinkk();
  //delay(3000);
 }
}



void enablemotor(){
 digitalWrite(enablepin,HIGH);
}


void movestep(int steps_to_move){
 int steps_left = abs(steps_to_move);

 if (steps_to_move > 0) { 
   step_direction = 1;
 }
 if (steps_to_move < 0) { 
   step_direction = 0;
 }


 while(steps_left > 0) {
   // if (millis() - last_step_time >= step_delay ) {
   //last_step_time = millis();
   if ( step_direction == 1 ){
     step_number++;
     delay(step_delay);
     if (step_number == number_of_steps) {
       step_number = 0;
     }
   }
   else {
     if (step_number ==0){
       step_number = number_of_steps;
     }
     step_number--;
   }
   steps_left--;


   stepmotor(step_number % 4);


   //} 
 }
}





void stepmotor(int thisStep){

 switch (thisStep) {
 case 0:    // 1010
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_1, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_2, LOW);
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_3, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_4, LOW);
   break;
 case 1:    // 0110
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_1, LOW);
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_2, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_3, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_4, LOW);
   break;
 case 2:    //0101
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_1, LOW);
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_2, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_3, LOW);
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_4, HIGH);
   break;
 case 3:    //1001
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_1, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_2, LOW);
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_3, LOW);
   digitalWrite(motor_pin_4, HIGH);
   break;
 } 

}

void blinkk(){
 for (int i = 0 ; i<30;i++){
   buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
   if (buttonState ==HIGH){
     break;
   }
   else{
     digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);   // set the LED on
     delay(blinkDelay);  // 968           // wait for a second
     digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);    // set the LED off
     delay(blinkDelay); //968
   } 
 }
}

void motoroff(){
 digitalWrite(enablepin,LOW);
 digitalWrite(motor_pin_1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(motor_pin_2, LOW);
 digitalWrite(motor_pin_3, LOW);
 digitalWrite(motor_pin_4, LOW);
```

Comment: What is your clock source?

Comment: I guess the value for blinkDelay is too low. How did you even get that value? Even so, the clock of the ATTiny2313 isn't that accurate. Better get an RTC chip of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to accurately control timings with `delay()`,
because you have to account for the time needed to execute the rest of
the code, including interrupts. You can easily have better accuracy by
using `millis()` like this:

```c
static unsigned long last_step_time;
unsigned long now = millis();
if (now - last_step_time >= step_delay) {
    do_one_step();
    last_step_time += step_delay;
}
```

This is almost what you have commented out in your own code, except that
`millis()` should be called only once per iteration, hence the `now`
variable.

This may still have less than perfect accuracy due to your clock source.
If your Arduino is clocked from a quartz you should be able to get
decent timing accuracy. If it is clocked from a ceramic oscillator you
are out of luck. In any case, you can always improve the accuracy by
calibrating your clock: you measure its drift and correct for it in
software. Then you have only to worry about thermal fluctuations of the
clock frequency, which should not be an issue with a quarts.

For best accuracy, you can use either an RTC or a watch crystal
connected directly to your ATmega chip. This last solution is only
possible if you go for a bare microcontroller, without the Arduino
board. See [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/9039)
for more details about this option, as well as the way to correct
for the drift in software.

Comment: the millis i used in my code was acting weird. the clock worked for 288 steps and then the step delay value would become zero and the motor would stall . i couldnt figure out what was wrong and went back to using delay. i will try your code .

Comment: @ekaggrat: Beware I just edited a mistake in the code above. `last_step_time` should be incremented by `step_delay` instead of becoming `now`, because it is intended to contain the time when the motor _should_ have been pulsed, irrespective of whether the pulse has been delayed by some interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using hardware timers (`millis()` uses this, see answer of edgarBonnet.

Or you might want to use a Real Time (Calendar) Clock chip, which often has even better accuracy (some even adjust to temperature).

Also a possibility is using a GPS module, and using the GPS time which should be extremely accurate and will not drift (since it's synchronized).

Post on AVR timer precision (hardware timers):
http://www.seanet.com/~karllunt/interval.html

RTC (Real Time Clock) example:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Real-Time-Clock-DS1302/

GPS example:
http://blog.arduino.cc/2014/01/06/simple-arduino-micro-gps-clock-project-arduinomicromonday/

Comment: `millis()` is based on a hardware timer, and is as accurate as your primary clock source.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I was unaware of that, edited it in my answer.
Though, you could say the primary clock source isn't 'accurate'.
It'll drift in time by temperature differences, some RTC's even adjust for this. And (somehow) synchronizing (gps?) would be the best way to go.

Comment: Yes. By “_as accurate as_” I mean: no more accurate, no less accurate. It’s synonymous with “_as inaccurate as_”.